# Trying to mimic browser website requests

Tags: python, ajax, google-chrome, browser

I'm trying to request html source from websites that check whether or not the the request was sent from a browser or not (chrome for example). Does anybody know how I can get all requests my computer is making along with the applications sending them? I'm just trying to get the truth of what my computer is sending without the possibility of anything being filtered.

Comment: Use selenium webdrivers. You can get for chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdriver is a good choice if you are sending the requests through a system which has a User Interface.

Else if you are using requests, try setting the user-agent and the required headers along with the request.